# Standard practice for validating a large number of parameters

Tags: validation, parameters

I am creating an Express.js API and am having trouble programming parameter validation eloquently. If I'm expecting 10-15 parameter variables for incoming POST requests what is the standard format for validating all of those variables?

Does anyone have any examples they could point at?

In my specific case I receive an Object (JavaScript) and I need to validate that the variable exist and are an accepted value. I do obviously know to test that it is set, and it is a string, and it is an excepted value etc. My question is really with the algorithm formatting.

Do I just have a validate function that goes through a giant if statement or what?